# Let video play using a slider

Tags: objective-c

I want to have a slider and a video(let's say one of 10 seconds) and when the slider is at 0 an imageView should be set to the first image of the video. When the slider is at 0.3 the imageView should show the image that's displayed at (3/10)*the length of the video (in this case 3 seconds). When the slider is at 1 the imageView should show the image that's displayed at the end of the video. So you could use the slider to play the video fast or slow.

Can someone tell me the code to get the image of a video at a specific second?

I don't want to play it from that second but just get the imaged that should normally be displayed at that second.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean to use `==` instead of `=` in both cases?

Comment: Are you sure you want `=` and not `==`?

Comment: And you're missing some `:` too.  Please show your real code.

Comment: sorry I want == but the error is still there

Comment: And isn’t it `integerForKey:@"myScoreLevel1"`?

Comment: You left out some colons (`:`).

Comment: Better read the basics of C / Objective-C

Comment: You dont have to simply edit your questions, you have to improve them. but what you did was barely an improvement. and honestly: I doubt you can improve them in a way that people will upvote them

Comment: ;( I'm really sad about this everything I do is bad.Could you give me some upvotes so I can ask a new question and prove that I can ask good questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because, in parsing `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey @"myScoreLevel1"]`, the compiler gets to "integerForKey" and sees a string literal after that.  That could never be legal syntax.  But `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey]` would be legal syntax, so the compiler complains of a missing `]`.

Of course, the real problem is the missing `:` after "integerForKey", but the compiler is not smart enough to realize that.

(And of course using `=` instead of `==` is another problem, but not one the compiler has recognized yet.  Using `=` in place of `==` is a far too common mistake, and it's one that you can't depend on the compiler always flagging.  If it gets through the compile your program can behave *very* strangely.)

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: @"myScoreLevel1"] == 0){
    [self.button1Outlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chooselevelWithoutStars.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

} else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: @"myScoreLevel1"] == 1){ 
    [self.button1Outlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chooseLevel1Star.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Also notice that the `else { .. }` is optional after the `if elseif` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Change to

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey :@"myScoreLevel1"] == 0){
    [self.button1Outlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chooselevelWithoutStars.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

} else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey :@"myScoreLevel1"] ==1){ 
    [self.button1Outlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chooseLevel1Star.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
} else {

}

Comment: No you have too many brackets it is [UIImage instead of [[UIImage